# ReCaptcha: hooking to TextBox's OnKeyDown from script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm working with ReCaptcha, ASP.NET and [Gaia Ajax](http://www.gaiaware.net). It took me some time to use the ReCaptcha AJAX APIs combined with Gaia to retrieve the contents of the `recaptcha_response_field` text box in AJAX postback through a patch.

This was just to introduce you to the subject. Now I would like to apply another patch to ReCaptcha, without reimplementing it (a comprehensive open source library that works better than current ASP.NET implementation would be desirable, but I have no time for that): [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355380/handling-enter-button-in-textbox-asp-net) explains which.

## Basically,

I need, after calling `ReCaptcha.Create()`, which renders the CAPTCHA during an AJAX postback, to hook to the OnKeyDown event of recaptcha_response_field and inject my Javascript snippet that prevents the form from being submitted.

You understand that since I don't render the `<input>` tag (I don't have control over it), I must hook from the external.

## In general,

I think you may actually answer the general question: "**how to set JavaScript event handlers programmatically?**" because this surely applies to all classes of events.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend on-the-fly checking of captcha, because then a program could just brute force it, after figuring out the basic characters of the picture.

I always use jquery for event handlers
something like:

```
  $(function() 
  {
    $("#{TEXTBOXID}").keydown(function(event)
    {
      alert(event.keyCode);
    });
  });
```

(taken from [Why does JQuery keydown work for window but not textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187229/why-does-jquery-keydown-work-for-window-but-not-textbox))

Comment: I just need to correctly submit the form when the user presses ENTER. I said that was a follow-up to another question